# Как преобразовать число в его экспоненциальную форму записи?

Tags: java

Есть строка, содержащая в себе некоторое число:

```
String s = "12345678901234567890";
```

Также там могут быть числа с плавающей запятой.
Как отобразить это число в экспоненциальной форме, если в полученном значении количество символов более 10, и в нормальной форме, если менее 10?

Comment: Ваш вопрос содержит  [Проблему ХY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/) Постарайтесь выделить основную суть вопроса. Не нагружайте отвечающего лишней информацией. Оставьте только вопрос на который можно дать однозначный ответ. Ведь ему не нужно знать откуда взято число и куда оно будет помещено?

Comment: Число нужно взять из edittext  умножить на некоторое число х и вывести в textview

Comment: @ruslanab: То есть ваша задача распадается на несколько: (1) какой тип данных подходит для операций с 20-значными числами, (2) дана строка с ~20 значащими цифрами, как преобразовать её в число того типа, который был получен в результате п. 1? (3) дано число, как управлять форматом вывода (включать экспоненциальную нотацию по условию).

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(s);
String result = n.length > 10()? n.toEngineeringString() : n.toPlainString();
```